# Elegant way to overcome Unlikely argument type for equals(): Stream<String> seems to be unrelated to String

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am looking for elegant way to overcome while comparing any Wrapper object to Stream.

Github working link: https://github.com/vishwaratna/Unlikely-argument-type-for-equals-Stream-String-/commit/d803f77c923e81fe7531ecb467561ac785d7aca5

*Question in reference*: [Filtering keys from map to list attribute in java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54742057/filtering-keys-from-map-to-list-attribute-in-java-8)

Recently i faced it while comparing member of `List` to a key of a `Map`.
I know there are other ways to compare without doing what i am doing but i am looking for in general casting, if it is available.

```
List<student> stulist = Arrays.asList(new student("1", "vishwa",null),
                                              new student("3", "Ravi",null),
                                              new student("2", "Ram",null));
```

---

```
        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap() {{
             put("1","20");
             put("2","30");
           }};
```

---

```
System.out.println( stulist.stream()
                    .filter(s->s.getId()
                    .equals(map.entrySet()
                    .stream() 
                    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)))
                    .count());
```

My code is compiling properly but the output is coming as **"0"**, whereas i expect output as **2**.

> I am sure it is due to type mismatch, **but why the compiler is not**
>   **throwing an error??**

**Warning that i am getting:** `Unlikely argument type for equals(): Stream<String> seems to be unrelated to String`

Comment: Your indentation may be cheating you. You are comparing `s->s.getID().equals(map.entrySet().stream().map(...))`. So in fact, you are comparing the `ID` (which is a string) to a stream you have created from a set. You should make sure that your comparison is between items of the same type.

Comment: I am asking how can i cast the later to former being in stream??

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you are asking. You  can't cast between a stream and a string. You have to define exactly what you want to do with that stream. Do you want to compare each of its elements to the `ID`? If so, what do you do if some are equal and the others are not? What is the result you want to achieve?

Comment: What is your code actually supposed to do?  Did you mean to check if the map has the key?  That would simply be `.filter(s->map.containsKey(s.getId())`

Comment: My code is supposed to count on basis of id field, I know the other way to achieve it but i wanna know how to convert stream to String type if any type cast is available.

Comment: **i am really not stressing on solution but on type conversion**

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: class names are always written in PascalCase, i.e. `student` should be `Student`. Second, you are using the raw type `HashMap`, it should be `HashMap<>`. Third, you shouldn't use the "double-brace construct", since it creates an unnecessary anonymous subclass of `HashMap`.

Comment: @Mc i am using other person question which is in reference. Thanks though for a nudge on conventions i really appreciate it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by converting between a Stream and a String? They're two entirely different things that cannot be compared. They're different concepts. It's like asking how to convert an apple into an distance. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what you might be intending to there could be:

```
System.out.println(stulist.stream()
        .filter(s -> map.keySet().contains(s.getId()))
        .count());
```

Second, the comparison using `equals` in your code is incorrect since its between objects of two different types of `String` and `Stream<String>`.

```
// here the 's.getId' is a String while 'map.entrySet()...map()' provides 'Stream<String>'
.filter(s -> s.getId().equals(map.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey)))
```

Comment: You did the same in 2nd code what i did, and its really not giving correct output sir.

Comment: @CommonMan `.filter(s -> map.keySet().contains(s.getId()))` is quite different from what your filter was doing. Still if the output is not what you desire, could you add to the question what further are you looking for?

Comment: i really appreciate your efforts but is there any way to cast stream to String or to any wrapper in general?

Comment: @CommonMan Not really sure what do you mean by casting a `Stream` to `String`, do you want to join them by any chance?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, to understand why compiler doesn't give an error, you should look into [String.equals()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) method implementation

```
    public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
        if (this == anObject) {
            return true;
        }
        if (anObject instanceof String) {
            String anotherString = (String)anObject;
            int n = value.length;
            if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
                char v1[] = value;
                char v2[] = anotherString.value;
                int i = 0;
                while (n-- != 0) {
                    if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                        return false;
                    i++;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Now, let's go back to this line:

```
s.getId().equals(map.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey))
```

As we know `s.getId()` is of type `String` and `map.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey)` is of type `Stream<String>`.

**Since `Stream<String>` is not `instanceof String`**, it's clear that `String.equals()` method will return `false` each time `s.getId()` is compared with `map.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey)` (hence, **0** count at the end). And compiler doesn't issue error, because **nothing illegal actually happened** (taking into account implementation of `String.equals()`).

Also, probably, cleanest way to find `count` without warnings would be:

```
System.out.println(
  stulist.stream()
         .map(Student::getId)
         .filter(map::containsKey)
         .count());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map.containsKey` to avoid running a stream on the entry set for each student entry:

```
long count = stulist.stream().map(student::getId).filter(map::containsKey).count();
```

You're getting the warning because it's being detected that you're testing `String.equals(Stream<String>)`, which of course is likely to be a bug (in your example, it's certainly is).

If you were to use your current logic, the proper check would have to be:

```
long count = stulist.stream()
                .filter(s -> map.entrySet()
                                .stream()
                                .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                                .anyMatch(s.getId()::equals))
                .count();
```

Comment: Thanks ernest, i really appreciate your efforts, i am able to get output by other logic but i want to know why no compilation error in above what i am doing?

Comment: The signature of `Object.equals` is `equals(Object other)`. So you can call `"string".equals(new Student())` or `Integer.valueOf(1).equals(new ArrayList<String>())` and you wouldn't get a compiler error. This is exactly what's happening. But IDEs (or the compiler perhaps) can detect that it's very unlikely that this what you meant to type (because `"string"` and `Student` are kind of apples to oranges comparison)